# Can receive but can not send email ubuntu 20.04

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, roundcube

I'm using Postfix, Roundcube 1.4.3 and devcot to receive and send emails on my vps server.

I'm able to receive emails but the errors are occurring when sending the email, the mail never reaches the destination.

Port `587` is what roundcube is using.

**Roundcube error.log**

```
[25-Dec-2021 07:18:35 +0000]: <669e8q7l> PHP Error: Connection refused (POST /?_task=mail&_unlock=loading1640416601599&_framed=1&_action=send)
[25-Dec-2021 07:18:35 +0000]: <669e8q7l> PHP Error: Failed to connect socket: Connection refused (POST /?_task=mail&_unlock=loading1640416601599&_framed=1&_action=send)
[25-Dec-2021 07:18:35 +0000]: <669e8q7l> SMTP Error: Connection failed: Failed to connect socket: Connection refused in /usr/share/roundcube/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube.php on line 1702 (POST /?_task=mail&_unlock=loading1640416601599&_framed=1&_action=send)
[25-Dec-2021 07:31:29 +0000]: <eb91q6is> PHP Error: Connection refused (POST /?_task=mail&_unlock=loading1640417491382&_framed=1&_action=send)
[25-Dec-2021 07:31:29 +0000]: <eb91q6is> PHP Error: Failed to connect socket: Connection refused (POST /?_task=mail&_unlock=loading1640417491382&_framed=1&_action=send)
```

*Error I'm getting in Roundcube ui*

```
SMTP Error (-1): Connection to server failed.
```

Comment: What is in the postfix log (/var/log/mail.log or similar)? What is the error there? If there is nothing, then the postfix server was not contacted at all, so check where Roundcube is configured to send mails.

Comment: SMTP is port tcp/25 and outbound connections to this port are generally blocked by most VPS providers, in a futile attempt to prevent spam. Please specify your VPS provider.